# Slice numpy array with other array

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to extract a subset of a a numpy array `y` specified by a set of indices contained in `x`, while still leaving some indices of `y` free. For a concrete example. Let `y` have shape `(10,10,10,3)` while `x` has shape `(7,7,3)`. The last dimension of `x` corresponds to indices info the first three dimensions of `y`. That is, I would like an efficient slicing operation with the same result as this:

```
for i in x.shape[0]:
    for j in x.shape[1]:
        z[i,j,:] = y[x[i,j,0],x[i,j,1],x[i,j,2],:]
```

Ideally the answer would work regardless of the number of dimensions of `x`.

In general, `y` would be `N+1`-dimensional, with shape `(...,N)`, while `x` would be `Q+1`-dimensional with shape `(...,N)`, and the result would have the same shape as `x`.

The motivation for this is extracting a subset of vectors from a vector field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work reasonably well:

```
y[x[..., 0], x[..., 1], x[..., 2]]
```

In general:

```
y[tuple(np.rollaxis(x, -1))]
```

Comment: The first version does what I want, but only when the number of dimensions of `y` is known beforehand. The second is general, but sadly seems to be very slow (20 times slower in one of my tests).